# Can anyone suggest a workflow maintaining Netsuite SDF with Git VCS?

Tags: git, version-control, netsuite, suitescript, sdf

We are trying to incorporate Netsuite SDF with Git. Do we have any standard process flow for this?

We need to find the best practices which streamlines the below actions

-> Creation & Maintaining Netsuite SDF project with multiple features/customisations.

-> Allow collaboration without Interrupting each other's work.
-> Code review

-> Maintaining various Environments (SandBoxes, Production)

Comment: Hi Santo, did you find an answer to your question? Were you looking to implement something like [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)?

Comment: @MartyC. I have a draft on this netsuite git flow based on the projects I worked. Will share shortly. Have to document

Comment: In breif @MartyC. We have to create branches with respect to environment. Sandbox production demo etc. This does not support CICD we should deploy manually

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up, Santo. I'm going to continue exploring this front to hopefully get CI/CD working. If Salesforce can support CI/CD, I really hope that NetSuite can as well! :)